# Having Separate Groupings for every Sheet

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Let's say we have a table in Tableau and there are a bunch of rows like the following table. Let's say in sheet 1 of Tableau we want to have two groups, Foods and Furniture. If we do this, in all the sheets, we will end up having these two groups.

In my case, I want to group rows differently in different sheets, let's say in the second sheet, I want to have Veggies, Fruits, and Furniture. How do I do that?

[image]